# Downloading from Play Store gives error 491

Tags: google-play-store

When I try to download anything from the Play Store it shows error 491 and can't finish the download. I have a Samsung Galaxy S 7582. How do I fix this?

Comment: All I had to do was clear the cache for services and store. No need to clear data and waste time re-entering your account details.

Comment: In our situation, the problem was that the clock was on the wrong time. User had disabled automatic date and time, clock was at least several hours off, and this caused lots of 491 errors. Sorry, can't post this as an answer, since I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do the following:

1. Open Settings
2. Go to Apps
3. Scroll down to Google Pay Services and open it
4. Clear data and cache
5. Do the same thing for the Google Play Store
6. Restart your phone
7. Open Google Play Store, let it sync, and you should be able to download whatever app was giving you error 491

Comment: Just a minor correction, it's "Google Play Services", not "Google Pay Services" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to play store properties page in your phone settings, and delete it's cache there, then reboot your phone, it should ask you to accept again terms of use when you start play store again.

Comment: It shouldn't ask you to agree to the TOS if you just clear the **cache**. Did you mean to specify clearing the **data** section instead?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings-Accounts-Google account-
Delete or Remove your account

Then go to Settings-Apps-All-Google play store
Clear Cache and Clear data

Reboot, Enter your account details again..

Comment: You really don't need to remove your account. You just need to clear data and cache for play services and play store.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing of the aforementioned worked for you, try to install APKpure or something similar. Then update Google Play and try to download the app you wanted. This was enough for me(htc desire 610, android 5.1.1, custom build), but you might consider mix of this solution and others, if that's not gonna work in your case.
Credit goes to [Frank Innocent's answer](https://www.nextpit.com/forum/600241/how-to-fix-google-play-error-491#2901278)